# How to implement interface with object.Clone conflicting method

Tags: java, methods, interface, java-5

I'd like to create a mock of this [XQPart](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Sonic/8.5.1/Docs8.5/api/esb_api/com/sonicsw/xq/XQPart.html) interface. The problem is that it extends an interface called [XQCloneable](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Sonic/8.5.1/Docs8.5/api/esb_api/com/sonicsw/xq/XQCloneable.html) which has a [clone](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Sonic/8.5.1/Docs8.5/api/esb_api/com/sonicsw/xq/XQCloneable.html#clone%28%29) method.

When I in Eclipse create a new class with this set as an interface, I get this class:

```
public class Part implements XQPart {}
```

With a red error squiggly under `Part` saying

> CloneNotSupportedException in throws clause of Object.clone() is not compatible with XQCloneable.clone()

What can I do here? Is there no way to make an implementation of this interface?

---

***Note:*** I did try to implement the method, but didn't realize I could skip the `throws` declaration as told in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344651/39321) so kept getting that error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your class inherits `Object.clone`, which is declared to throw `CloneNotSupportedException`. On the other hand, your class implements `XQCloneable`, whose `clone` has no `throws` clause. If you just create an empty declaration `public Object clone() { return null; }`, it will make your class compatible with the interface.

Comment: Ah, thanks, there we go. I knew I had to implement the method, just couldn't for the live of me figure out how as I kept getting that error. Removing the `throws` declaration fixed it right up :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a mock object for unit testing, you need to implement the method (even if it is a no-op). Mocking an interface will require empty methods to match the requirements of the interface. Just make sure the unit you are testing doesn't require the no-op method.

Answer (score 0):

As @Emmerich states, the error happens because `XQCloneable` extends the [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface, which is sort of a funny concoction as the `clone()` method is actually not defined therein, but rather in the `Object` class!

The semantics is that it shall be possible to create a attribute-by-attribute copy of classes that implement `Cloneable` and that these classes must `@Override` the `clone()` method, as the `Object` version just throws the `CloneNotSupportedException`.

Whether your mock and uni test needs to create a copy/clone of the `XQPart` implementation is up to you to decide/determine - in most cases I would not expect so and just have the method return null or the identity.

Cheers,